# Reducing pricing cost in azure after creating a service plan

Tags: azure

I have created a service plan to host web apps, but while creating I didn't keep an eye on the pricing details, so gave a standard pricing.
Now I want to reduce it to basic pricing, can I do it?
I can only see the pricing for it, but not able to change it.
Because I have changed the pricing tag for `databases`.
Thanks in Advance!!!!!

Comment: There should be a Scale Up option on the plan. You can change tiers from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could scale up your pricing tier under App Service---Settings.

[image]

For detailed information, such as VM sizes for each pricing tier, see [App Service Pricing Details](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/). For a table of service limits, quotas, and constraints, and supported features in each tier, see [App Service limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits).

Comment: Thanks mate, i hope it doesn't affect the web app that is in there.

Comment: @Grijan That will be fine.